# Parse url and use part after the last slash

Tags: php, mysql

I have one page whose last word is a field in my MySQL table.

Its like that:

```
 www.xyz.com/etc/demo
 www.xyz.com/etc/dddred
 www.xyz.com/etc/dffgfffre
```

The word `demo` has a record in MySQL, so do the other words. So for each example a different record will be chosen. I want to pass this word into a SQL query. I have created one page `www.xyz.com/etc/abc.php` that executes the query, but I dont know how to get and put the value of `city` into the WHERE clause.

```
  $res = myl_query("SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE city=''");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use can use this

```
$c=explode("/",$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]);

$city=end($c);
```

than use

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE city='{$city}'");
```

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated so use `PDO`  or `mysqli`

```
$res=$pdo->preapre("SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE city=:city");
$res->execute(array(":city"=>$city));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url =  $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
preg_match('/\/([-/])$/', $url, $m);
$city = $m[0];
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE city='".$city."'");
```

Comment: Regular expressions are overkill when something like `substr($str, strrpos($str, '/'))` will work perfectly well...